# Merge pdf with the same dimension

Tags: pdftex

I use below code to merge pdf files (all pdfs are the same dimensions):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-]{1.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-]{2.pdf}
\end{document}
```

But it will change the dimension to a4paper, how can I do it to use original document dimension?

1. page dimension (widthxheight) keep the same as original document.e.g. original document is 8.5x14in, but current output a4paper is 8.27x11.69in.
2. page should not be scaled.such as fonts or images keep the same as original document.
3. page should not add extra border or margin.
4. Just like two document but merged to one document.

I try standalone call but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you just want to turn off `autoscale`? Then just add `noautoscale` to the options.

Comment: @cfr I wish to keep everything the same as original document, for example, my input document is 8.5x14in, but the output a4paper is 8.27x11.69in.

Comment: You need to be clearer in your question, then, that you aren't just asking about how to avoid scaling. As it stands, your code will scale the pages and you don't seem aware of that. If that's not the problem, you obviously need to explain that and say why you're not avoiding the scaling, if you don't want it. I mean, it sounds as if avoiding the scaling is part of what you want, even though you apparently want something else, too.

Comment: @lucky1928: You want to use same dimension of the input paper and then print it on a smaller paper without loss? You could try to squeeze an elephant into some fridge as well ;-)

Comment: If you're asking about changing the paper size mid-document, there's a question about that somewhere. However, I can't tell whether that is or isn't what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fitpaper option:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
blblb
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{example-image-a5-landscape.pdf}
\includepdf[pages=-,fitpaper]{example-image-a5.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, sounds like need to remove [a4paper] also. if keep [a4paper] there, the dimension will be 8.27x11.69in. if I remove [a4paper], then output result will be 8.50x14in, which is the same as original document.

Comment: Well if you don't want a4paper then naturally you should use whatever paper option you really want. But it won't affect the pdf's inserted with includepdf and the fitpaper option.